# Ordem de funcionamento dos scripts

Tags: javascript

Sou iniciante em java script e quando executo este programa se tiverem os 2 campos em branco so aparece o primeiro aviso mas depois se preencher o primeiro campo o segundo aviso já alguem me pode explicar o porque e como fixar?

```
function valida_form (){            
            if(document.getElementById("adicionanomeparagem").value == ""){
                var div = document.getElementById("validacaonomeparagem");
                div.innerText = "Não pode estar vazio!"
                return false;
            }
        if (document.getElementById(validacaonomeparagem)!="")
        {

        document.getElementById("validacaonomeparagem").innerText = ""


        }
     if(document.getElementById("adicionalatitudeparagem").value == ""){
                var div = document.getElementById("validacaolatitudeparagem");
                div.innerText = "Não pode estar vazio!"
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece porque tu retornas logo um false. logo, se a função manda logo um false para naquele momento.

```
function valida_form (){            
            preenchido=true;
            if(document.getElementById("adicionanomeparagem").value == ""){
                var div = document.getElementById("validacaonomeparagem");
                div.innerText = "Não pode estar vazio!";
                preenchido=false;
            }
        if (document.getElementById(validacaonomeparagem)!="")
        {

        document.getElementById("validacaonomeparagem").innerText = "";


        }
     if(document.getElementById("adicionalatitudeparagem").value == ""){
                var div = document.getElementById("validacaolatitudeparagem");
                div.innerText = "Não pode estar vazio!";
                preenchido=false;
            }
            return preenchido;
        }
```

Faz desta forma, onde dizes se é true ou false numa flag que só depois é retomada!
Força nisso!

Comment: Com o teu código vai somente funcionar o ultimo e obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Tenta agora com a alteração que eu fiz, faz mesmo copy->paste sff

Comment: Tenta agora com a alteração que eu fiz, faz mesmo copy->paste sff

Comment: Continua igual ...

Answer (score 0):

Como apontado pelo Pedro, você deve validar todos os campos antes de fazer o retorno. em todo caso, te aconselho à também reaproveitar o codigo que verifica se o campo está preenchido.

```js
var nome = {
  input: document.getElementById("adicionanomeparagem"),
  valida: document.getElementById("validacaonomeparagem"),
  error: "Informe um Nome para a Paragem"
};

var latitude = {
  input: document.getElementById("adicionalatitudeparagem"),
  valida: document.getElementById("validacaolatitudeparagem"),
  error: "Informe uma Latitude para a Paragem"
};

var validaCampo = function (campo) {
  var isValid = campo.input.value ? true : false;
  campo.valida.innerText = isValid ? "" : campo.error;
  return isValid;
}

function valida_form (){ 
  var isValid = true;
  isValid = isValid & validaCampo(nome);
  isValid = isValid & validaCampo(latitude);
  return isValid;
}
```

```css
.valida {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div>
    <label>
      Nome Paragem:
      <input id="adicionanomeparagem" type="text" />
    </label>
    <span id="validacaonomeparagem" class="valida"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>
      Latitude Paragem:
      <input id="adicionalatitudeparagem" type="text" />
    </label>
    <span id="validacaolatitudeparagem" class="valida"></span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" onclick="valida_form()" value="Validar" />
  </div>
</form>
```